# Given an unzoned DateTime and a timezone, how can I construct an instant in NodaTime?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, nodatime

I have a `DateTime` constructed explicitly.

```
var myDateTime = new DateTime(2015,1,1,0,0,0);
```

I have a timezone obtained explicitly.

```
var myTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Los_Angeles"];
```

`myDate` is known to be represented in `myTimeZone`

How should I use this information to generate a `ZonedDateTime` or an `Instant` using NodaTime?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain how I can improve the question?

Comment: Seems clear enough to me.  Not sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert your `DateTime` to a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(myDateTime);
```

Then you can assign it to a zone:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.InZoneLeniently(myTimeZone);
```

And map it back to an instant:

```
Instant instant = zdt.ToInstant();
```

Comment: But the datetime is **not** in my local timezone.

Comment: "local" in `LocalDateTime` does not mean "local for you".  It just means local for *somebody*.  It is detached from all time zone information.   It is just a date and a time, just like a `DateTime` with `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

Comment: In other words, it's not the same definition as `DateTimeKind.Local`, which *does* mean "local for you".

Comment: @Matthew: And yes, we're aware that causes confusion :( If I had a *really good* alternative, I'd consider the massive breaking change of renaming it for 2.0... but I haven't heard anything better, so far.